# Inheritance from MainWindow problem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I wrote a program to control device with serial port. It works fine but I'd like to seperate the class which would operate serial ports. I also want to have acess to buttons, comboboxes, etc. from this class.

Here are most important parts of code:

Serialsettings header:

```
#ifndef SERIALSETTINGS_H
#define SERIALSETTINGS_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include "mainwindow.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class SerialSettings : public MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    struct Settings
    {
        QString name;
        qint32 baudRate;
        QString stringBaudRate;
        QSerialPort::DataBits dataBits;
        QString stringDataBits;
        QSerialPort::Parity parity;
        QString stringParity;
        QSerialPort::StopBits stopBits;
        QString stringStopBits;
        QSerialPort::FlowControl flowControl;
        QString stringFlowControl;
    };

    explicit SerialSettings(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SerialSettings();
    Settings settings() const;
signals:
private:
    void fillPortsInfo();
    void fillPortsParameters();
    void updateSettings();

private:
    Settings m_currentSettings;
};

#endif
```

Serialsettings source:

```
#include "serialsettings.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

SerialSettings::SerialSettings(QWidget *parent)
    : MainWindow(parent)

{

    //some functions
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPort>
//#include "serialsettings.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class SerialSettings;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow  
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
     ~MainWindow();
    // some code
};
#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "serialsettings.h"
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  //some code
};

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I don't have any error at this moment but it finishes with: The program has unexpectedly finished.

Could you help me please with this problem?

Comment: Please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's impossible to reproduce the issue with the code you posted. Also, you may want to take a good look at the Qt QSerialPort examples and use them as a base.

Comment: ***The program has unexpectedly finished.*** You need to use a debugger to figure out why. I don't see it in the code that is presented.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm its SIGSEGV, I'll check if there is some pointer that causes this fault.